# How to make sure video script in JMeter is actually working? Type a message

Tags: scripting, jmeter, video-streaming, mp4, jmeter-plugins

I have a url https://www.dummyvideo.com/ As soon as this url is hit, there is a single video which starts playing. When I check on browser, segment is not showing in response. Same is the case in JMeter. I would like to know which protocol should I use for acfor achieving this goal. Also, how do I conclude that if my script is working as I dont see segment response on browser as well as on JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, **JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

The video is being "played" via JavaScript function call and JMeter doesn't automatically "play" the video as it's not capable of executing JavaScript

Since your URL doesn't lead to the website with the video I can only give general recommendations:

1. If it's possible to find out the exact URL of the video from the page source you can extract it using a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and add another [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler which will download the video
2. If the video is in form of [M3U](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U) playlist you can use [JMeter HLS Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/HLS-3.0-Release/) which parses the playlist and gets media streams out of it
3. In both cases make sure to add a relevant [Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) to simulate the user watching the video before proceeding to next page/iteration

Comment: yes i got the direct link that is in .mp4.., What are you expecting me to extract as I don't see any response on request url.